# Unable to connect to host MySQL database on application deployed to CloudBees

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I followed the instructions [here](https://run.cloudbees.com/a/xinco#db-manage%3axincodemo) but when attempted I got the following error:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Xinco Demo Publish/Xinco/target/Xinco-2012-08-30_00-20-05.war at hudson.remoting.Channel@1fc6bdea:s-50b0ae50
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:783)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:769)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:108)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:707)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:660)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:629)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1433)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.util.IOException2: Server.InternalError - Invalid WEB-INF/cloudbees-web.xml: resource
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable.deployFile(Deployable.java:151)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable$DeployFileCallable.invoke(Deployable.java:342)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2048)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: Server.InternalError - Invalid WEB-INF/cloudbees-web.xml: resource
    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.readResponse(BeesClient.java:850)
    at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.applicationDeployArchive(BeesClient.java:435)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.deployables.Deployable.deployFile(Deployable.java:123)
    ... 11 more
Build step 'Deploy to CloudBees' marked build as failure
```

The full output can be seen [here](https://xinco.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Xinco%20Demo%20Publish/4/console).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: Server.InternalError - Invalid WEB-INF/cloudbees-web.xml: resource
```

Your `cloudbees-web.xml` doesn't follow the correct format.

See http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml - as the `cloudbees-web.xml` needs to be wrapped in an outer `<cloudbees-web-app>` element

Comment: This did the trick. I guess the issue is on the documentation. Nowhere it points to an example of the whole cloudbees.web.xml file.

Comment: I was unable to test this fix due to other errors in the code. Today I finally was able to and I'm still getting errors. See here: http://xincodemo.xinco.cloudbees.net/

Comment: That's a totally different error.  You should close this question and open a new question that deals with that - since you're going to need to post the error trace as part of the question. Otherwise it all gets too confusing to follow later on.

Comment: Created another question as requested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747969/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-in-cloudbees-communicationsexception-communications

Answer (score 0):

You also don't have to use cloudbees-web.xml if you don't want - if you bind your app to a DB it will make it available as a named datasource automatically.

(see bees app:bind command).

You only have to do this once - and then the app will know about the datasource.

http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management

and

https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide

(sorry, still working on docs).

Comment: My application was not done via the SDK. Is there a way to do that anyway?

Comment: Sorry ! not at this time :( http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK for how to install it.