# Unable to connect to MySQL in Cloudbees CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

It was requested from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206808/unable-to-connect-to-host-mysql-database-on-application-deployed-to-cloudbees/) question to post a different question.

I did as recommended in the question above and corrected the cloudbees.xml file correctly. But even then I can't connect. Here's the stack trace:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Error Code: 0
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1010)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:98)
root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Error Code: 0
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:602)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getProtectedEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:574)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:565)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.updateDBState(XincoDBManager.java:280)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:125)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:102)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco.init(Xinco.java:197)
    com.vaadin.Application.start(Application.java:551)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.startApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1219)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:484)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:98)
root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Error Code: 0
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:319)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:138)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:213)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getProtectedEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:574)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:565)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.updateDBState(XincoDBManager.java:280)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:125)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:102)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco.init(Xinco.java:197)
    com.vaadin.Application.start(Application.java:551)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.startApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1219)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:484)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:98)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2393)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:213)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getProtectedEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:574)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:565)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.updateDBState(XincoDBManager.java:280)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:125)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:102)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco.init(Xinco.java:197)
    com.vaadin.Application.start(Application.java:551)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.startApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1219)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:484)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:98)
root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2393)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:685)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:213)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getProtectedEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:574)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.getEntityManager(XincoDBManager.java:565)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.updateDBState(XincoDBManager.java:280)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:125)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.XincoDBManager.reload(XincoDBManager.java:102)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco.init(Xinco.java:197)
    com.vaadin.Application.start(Application.java:551)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.startApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1219)
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:484)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:98)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

Comment: What does the setup code for your database connection look like?  It looks like your database connection is connecting to the wrong thing (and it is doing it so quickly, I'd assume localhost).  Some code snippets from com.bluecubs.xinco.core.server.vaadin.Xinco.init might help.

Comment: You can find source here: https://xinco.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xinco/trunk/Xinco

Answer (score 3):

This is a common MySQL connection timeout, need to configure the connection pool to check returned connection is live, read related documentation "[avoiding database idle timeouts](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide)" :

use a validation query in you connection pool settings :

```
<param name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
```

you also should consider using [database binding](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management), as cloudbees-web.xml is deprecated :

```
bees app:bind -a APP_ID -db DB_ID validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

Comment: Is there a way of unbinding the database from the app? I forgot to add the validation query part of it.

Comment: Was unable to make it work. Added the validation query on the connection pool settings without luck.